# rewrite url with get variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to write `<a href="product.php?id=5">`as product/5.I am not talking about user to type doamin.com/product/5 to get the result, what I am looking for is- when user click the link, the browser address bar will show the url as domain.com/product/5.

Is it possible?Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: ....change the href location to "/product/5"? What are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write:

```
<a href="/product/5">LINK</a>
```

What you also need is a **.htaccess** file, that handles **mod_rewrite**, for example:

```
# turn mod_rewrite engine on 
RewriteEngine On

# rewrite all physical existing file or folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# allow things that are certainly necessary
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/css/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/images/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/javascript/"

# rewrite rules
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_route=$1 [QSA]
```

With you'll get a **$_GET['_route']** which's value will be **/product/5**. The rest is up to your php code to parse that string.

Comment: Thank You very much,its working fine.
As I am a new to this field, just for knowledge - is it the safe method to do this way?Am I thinking in right direction to handle $_get[] in this way?I heard that it is good for SEO.And if you could recommend some good article for be-gainers.Thanks again.

Comment: This method is as safe as "?id=5". Its up to you, how "secure" you handle the variables you get. It will definitely enhance your SEO and it will also make it easier to share your links. Imagine this on a phone: "Hey dude, check this out: domain.com/product=128e947dje747" or just "domain.com/redshirt" :) but don't overdo it. A domain like "/Red-Shirt-With-Sprinkles-And-Blue-Neck-By-Company" would not increase readability and SEO. And as a last tip: use "-" instead of "_" in your URLs, as google likes this more. If you want further information search for "mod_rewrite", "clean URL", "Slug" … :)